# Laravel 5.8 Eloquent query without using DB::raw() -- get rows based on latest value of many to many relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

My goal is to select all issues that have been marked as false-positive. The issues are connected to `Status` via a ManyToMany relationship with pivot table `IssuesStatus`. The current status of an issue is determined by the value of the `status` column on the `Status` table.

I've come up with a solution that works but seems somehow suspect. I'm looking for a way to rewrite the query using Eloquent query builder without relying on the `DB::raw()` method.

```
public function getFalsePositivesAttribute() {
    return Issue::where(DB::raw(
        '( select `status` '.
        'from `issues-status` '.
        'left join `status` on `status`.id = `issues-status`.status_id '.
        'where `issues-status`.issue_id = `issues`.id '.
        'order by `issues-status`.id desc limit 1 )'
    ), '=', 'false-positive')->get();
}
```

Example of desired SQL query:

```
SELECT
    `Issues`.id
FROM
    `issues` AS `Issues`
LEFT JOIN
    `issues-status` `IssueStatus` on `Issues`.id = `IssueStatus`.issue_id
LEFT JOIN
    `status` as `StatusTable` on `IssueStatus`.status_id = `StatusTable`.id
WHERE
    `Issues`.report_id = 2
AND
    ( 
        SELECT
            `status`
        FROM
            `issues-status` `IssueStatus`
        LEFT JOIN
            `status` `StatusTable` on `StatusTable`.id = `IssueStatus`.status_id
        WHERE
            `IssueStatus`.issue_id = `Issues`.id
        ORDER BY
            `IssueStatus`.id desc
        LIMIT 1
    ) = 'false-positive'
GROUP BY
    `Issues`.id
```

Models:

```
class Issue extends Model {
    ...

    public function status() {
        return $this->belongsToMany( Status::class, 'issues-status')
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->withPivot('note');
    }

    ...
} 

class Status extends Model {
    ...

    public function issues() {
        return $this->hasMany(Issue::class);
    }

    ...
}
```

Tables:

```
Issues:
  id - identity

Status
  id - identity
  status - string

IssueStatus
  id - identity
  issue_id - relation to Issues
  status_id - relation to Status
  created_at - timestamp
  note - text
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you want to fetch the issue where the latest status is equals to something.

Add a `latestStatus` function to your `Issues` model:

```php
public function latestStatus()
{
    return $this->hasMany(IssueStatus::class)->latest();
}
```

Now, swap your `status` function with this one:

```php
public function status() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( Status::class, 'issues-status')
       ->withTimestamps()
       ->withPivot('note');
}
```

Then:

```php
//Get all issues which has the desired status
Issue::whereHas('status', function($query){
    $query->where('id', $desiredStatusId);
})
->get()
->reject(function($issue){ 
    //filter the collection by the latest issue status,
    // and reject those who does not have the desired latest status;
    return $issue->latestStatus()->first()->status_id != $desiredStatusId;
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm wondering if this approach will get me to where I need to be. It looks like the `reject` method is filtering our the results at the application level. Ideally I would like to filter out all rows that don't match the desired `status_id` before the results are returned.

Comment: Yes, it filter the results at the application level. Trying to figure out a way to filter this results with the database query.

Comment: I think it's not possible unless you use the DB::raw() to manually execute your query.  Why can't you filter the result at the application level?

Comment: I would like to return the query and pass it to other methods so they can modify it or add too it or whatever. Once I have the results it's too late.

Comment: So i think you need to use the DB raw, because the `whereHas`returns all occurrences for the issue_id on `issuestatus` table, and you can't use the `first()` to fetch only the last status.